# When to set the Audio Session properties

Tags: objective-c, audio

When is the best time at which I should set the audio session properties?

In the app, I am using the PlayAndRecord category and I am getting some input from the user and then playing it back.

Right now I set all the audio session properties before each input and output. And it seems to take up to half a second to set those properties. Where would you recommend me to do this, to not have that delay before each input/output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it in the constructor of an object that is created at app startup. Once the properties have been set, they can be forgotten assuming that they do not need to change during the life of the app.